# Javascript Pass Array as a Parameter to a Function with Multiple Parameters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a string variable and two arrays to a global function.  Something like this:

```
function send_times_to_device(stop_name, times, headsigns) {
  // function code here
}
```

Later in code:

```
...
var stop_name = "temp";
var times = new Array(json.length);
var headsigns = new Array(json.length);
...
if(times.length < 6){
  send_times_to_device(stop_name, times, headsigns);
}
...
```

How would I do this correctly in Javascript?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
You guys were right, there was an error elsewhere in my code, this works!

Comment: Is there an error here?

Comment: I don't see a problem

Comment: that seems technically correct

Comment: Did you meant "Using an array as arguments to call a function with multiple parameters"?

Answer (score 1):

new Array(n), creates an array with n undefined entries in it.

If you want to create an array with an integer value as the first entry use :

```
function send_times_to_device(stop_name, times, headsigns) {
  // function code here
    console.log(stop_name);
    console.log(times);
    console.log(headsigns);
}

var stop_name = "temp";
var times = [json.length];
var headsigns = [json.length];

send_times_to_device(stop_name, times, headsigns);
```